# Dot product between transpose of sparse matrix and vector in python scipy

Tags: scipy, sparse-matrix, transpose, dot-product

I know the function spmat.dot(vec) that returns the standard matrix vector 'dot' product between a sparse matrix spmat and a numpy array vec in scipy.

I need to compute transpose(spmat).dot(vec). Is there a built in function that does exactly this ?
During my research, I stumbled upon scipy.sparse.linalg.LinearOperator.rmatvec, but it does not seem to be available in my scipy version.

Thanks,

Comment: Sparse does provide a transpose. Read the docs.

Comment: Sparse transpose is usually free, as well - it's the same underlying data arrays interpreted differently. `spmat.T.dot(vec)` should work.

Comment: Thanks @CJR, this is exaclty the answer I needed. If you transform your comment into an answer, I'll accept it.